# Need help with a proof involving limits

Tags: real-analysis

Given a metric space $(X,d)$,and given a sequence $a_{i,j}$ I want to show that if $\lim_{i\to\infty}a_{i,j}$ is uniform in $j$, then $\varepsilon>0$ there is some natural number $M$ such that $d(a_{i,j},y_i)<\varepsilon$ for all $j\geq M$. then this is true

$$\lim_{i\to\infty}\lim_{j\to\infty}a_{i,j}=\lim_{j\to\infty}\lim_{i\to\infty}a_{i,j}$$

since  $\lim_{i\to\infty}a_{i,j}$ is uniform in $j$, we have $\lim_{i\to\infty}d(a_{i,j},y_i)<\varepsilon$, for this to work we need to assume that these limits exist $y_i=\lim_{j\to\infty}a_{i,j}$, $y=\lim_{i\to\infty}y_i$, $x_j=\lim_{i\to\infty} a_{i,j}$, $x=\lim_{j\to\infty}x_j$. then we have $\lim_{i\to\infty}d(a_{i,j},y_i)<\varepsilon\implies d(x_j,y)<\varepsilon$. I'm not sure how to do this,  for this to exist we need to have $$\lim_{i\to\infty}y_i=\lim_{j\to\infty}x_j\implies y=x$$ Does it suffice to assume $a_{i,j}$ converges to both $x$ and $y$, then show that this is indeed true? Or do I need to use the triangle inequality such that $$\lim_{i\to\infty}d(a_{i,j},y_i)\leq d(a_{i,j},x_j)+d(x_j,y_i)+d(y_i,y)<3\varepsilon$$

Comment: I think it means the *usual* metric.

Comment: @Gae.S. it means that $d(x,y)=|x-y|$

Comment: wait my bad, the fact that it was equipped with the cannonical metric was from a priror problem. I'll fix the main post now, I am so sorry.